# Does Moqui support saving content in Apache Jackrabbit / Viewing Content History / Checkout / Checkin

Tags: jackrabbit, moqui, content-management, document-management

Browsing thru Moqui online documentation, i found the below references about Apache Jackrabbit, which suggests Moqui supports using Apache Jackrabbit as a content resource,
However it is not clear to me, if Moqui supports Saving contents in Apache Jackrabbit,
I came across a few Content / File upload screens in Hivemind, but i could not tell if the content can be saved in Apache Jackrabbit and if Moqui has user interface to do the common Document Management operations like Checkout, Checkin, View History etc,
I would really appreciate if someone can confirm this and point me to an example screen in the existing Moqui based applications like PopCommerce or Hivemind that uses Apache Jackrabbit for Document / Content Management.

- Implementations of the ResourceReference interface can be implemented as needed and default implementations exist for the following protocols/schemes: http, https, file, ftp, jar, classpath, component, and content (JCR, i.e., Apache Jackrabbit).
- content:// for resources in a content repository (JCR, via Jackrabbit client); the first path element after the protocol prefix is the name of the content repository as specified in the repository.name attribute in the Moqui Conf XML fil
- The contentLocation points to a Resource Facade location so the content can be in a database (with the DbResource/File entities), a JCR (Java Content Repository, such as Apache JackRabbit),
- JCR 2.0 (JSR-283) based content and artifact management for Apache JackRabbit or other JCR implementations
  **

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports it. You set moqui.security.UserGroupPreference to use JCR as default as per https://github.com/moqui/moqui-runtime/tree/master/jackrabbit.

Unsure about the extent of the Jackrabbit interface easily available to use beyond the standard Moqui content services.

Comment: Thanks Ronan, will try and continue exploring document management interface including checkout, checkin, version history etc.